# Populate the JSON Array with data from the Arraylist in android

Tags: android, arrays

please help me. I am trying to put values on my json array from the values of the arraylist, but unfortunately, I don't know why, my json array only gets the last value of the arraylist. I expect an output of

```
[{"Id":"1"},{"Id":"2"},{"Id":"3"}]
```

but it gives me

```
[{"Id":"3"},{"Id":"3"},{"Id":"3"}]
```

Can you help me get out of this. Thanks in advance, here is my code:

```
try

    {
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject brand = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject consumerSegments = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jArrayReportUpload = new JSONArray();

        try {
            JSONArray jArraySubrands = new JSONArray();
            JSONArray jArrayConsumerSegments = new JSONArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < arraylist_SUBBRANDS.size(); i++) 
            {
                brand.put("Id", _brands.get(i));
                Log.d("Brand: " + i, _brands.get(i));
                jArraySubrands.put(brand);
            }
            Log.d("JSONbrand", jArraySubrands.toString());

            for (int j = 0; j < arraylist_SEGMENTS.size(); j++) {
                consumerSegments.put("Id",_segments.get(j));
                Log.d("Segment: " + j, _segments.get(j));
                jArrayConsumerSegments.put(consumerSegments);
            }
            Log.d("JSONsegment", jArrayConsumerSegments.toString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put  `JSONObject consumerSegments = new JSONObject();`

as the first statement inside

```
for (int j = 0; j < arraylist_SEGMENTS.size(); j++) {
```

and not where it currently is, you are just overwriting a memory block with the same values rather than creating a new instance to hold the new values everytime